# How to effectively set project default encoding in SublimeText2?

Tags: character-encoding, sublimetext2, opensuse

I have sublime-project file as follows:

```
{
"default_encoding": "Central European (ISO 8859-2)",
"fallback_encoding": "Central European (ISO 8859-2)",
"folders":
[
    {
        "folder_exclude_patterns":
        [
            "*.Trash*"
        ],
        "follow_symlinks": true,
        "path": "cok_gnb"
    },
    {
        "follow_symlinks": true,
        "path": "Dokumenty"
    }
],
"settings":
{
    "line_padding_bottom": 3,
    "tab_size": 4
}
}
```

options: "default_encoding" and "fallback_encoding" make no effect - when I open ST2 files are already open with Windows 1252 encoding.

What's wrong? Maybe there's another option to force ST2 to use the encoding?

It is frustrating when I forget to use "Open with encoding" menu option and mess large file and sometimes I have to remove it and pull from repo again.

I use OpenSuse 12.3.

Comment: I don't have an answer but did you try this: http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=11688

Answer (score 9):

You should place `"default_encoding"` and `"fallback_encoding"` into `"settings"`

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "folder_exclude_patterns":
            [
                "*.Trash*"
            ],
            "follow_symlinks": true,
            "path": "cok_gnb"
        },
        {
            "follow_symlinks": true,
            "path": "Dokumenty"
        }
    ],
    "settings":
    {
        "default_encoding": "Central European (ISO 8859-2)",
        "fallback_encoding": "Central European (ISO 8859-2)",
        "line_padding_bottom": 3,
        "tab_size": 4
    }
}
```